# arreglos, arrays, vectores java

Tags: java, array, netbeans

Hola que tal estoy haciendo un ejercicio en java y quiero saber alguna forma para recorrer un arreglo que suponiendo tiene 10 posiciones; primero quiero mostrar el elemento de la posición 0, después el elemento de la posición 9, después el elemento de la posición 1, luego el elemento de posición 8, después el elemento de la posición 2 y así sucesivamente de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: No te voy a dar una respuesta,  porque quiero motivarte a ver si tu mismo podrias hacerlo,  para ello te voy a dar una pista,  hay dos formas,  la primera es declarar una variable entera por fuera del for y figurar el porque deberia estar fuera y para que deberias usarla, y dentro del ciclo en vez de iterar por todos los elementos, iterar nada mas por la mitad.

Comment: La otra forma es hacer esto mismo, pero haciendo un ciclo for inverso hasta la mitad tambien ( depende de lo que prefieras), pero ambas son validas y no afectan el performance.

Comment: ok muchas gracias Riven

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow! Acostúmbrate a incluir el código que tengas hecho en la pregunta, eso demuestra tu esfuerzo y dedicación al problema que estás tratando de resolver :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Necesitas usar un bucle FOR similar a este:

```
for (var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
        console.log("Valor de i: " + i + "Valor de palabra.length-i-1: " +(palabra.length - i - 1) );
        if (palabra[i] != palabra[palabra.length - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

El ejemplo que te he puesto esta en JavaScript pero es fácilmente transportable a Java.

Espero que te ayude el ejemplo, si necesitas mas ayuda agrega comentarios.

Comment: muchas gracias Jose

Comment: Si crees que mi respuesta es correcta y valida para lo que solicitabas en tu pregunta considera marcarla como respuesta correcta para ayudar a otros compañeros con el mismo problema.

Comment: oye tengo una duda hice mi ciclo así pues estoy trabajando sobre el main 
´
 for(int i = 0 ;i<numeros.length;i ++){
            System.out.println(i +". Numero: "+numeros[i]);
            System.out.println((numeros.length - i - 1)+". Numero: "+numeros[numeros.length - i - 1]);
            //(numeros.length - i - 1));           
        }
´

Comment: y cual es la duda???

Comment: jaja perdon es que mi resultado mi resultado me arroja mas salidas de las esperadas
1. Digite un numero: 1
2. Digite un numero: 2
3. Digite un numero: 3
4. Digite un numero: 4
5. Digite un numero: 5
6. Digite un numero: 6
7. Digite un numero: 7
8. Digite un numero: 8
9. Digite un numero: 9
10. Digite un numero: 0
0. Numero: 1
9. Numero: 0
1. Numero: 2
8. Numero: 9
2. Numero: 3
7. Numero: 8
3. Numero: 4
6. Numero: 7
4. Numero: 5
5. Numero: 6
5. Numero: 6
4. Numero: 5
6. Numero: 7
3. Numero: 4
7. Numero: 8
2. Numero: 3
8. Numero: 9
1. Numero: 2

Comment: perdon soy nuevo aqui no le se dar formato a esto

Comment: creo que ya entendi mi error

Comment: ya quedo Jose muchas gracias

Comment: En stackoverflow no solemos dar respuestas a preguntas que no incluyan un código, eso demuestra el esfuerzo y dedicación por parte del OP.